# How to make PDO (pdo_pgsql) to lazily fetch rows

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

With the following code even though I fetch a single row - the whole dataset is downloaded (which takes few seconds):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id > :position ORDER BY id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute([
    ':position' => $position,
]);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    break;
}
```

I tried to find an option in PDO that would make it fetch rows on demand (or by reasonable batches), but failed to do so, at least I could not find it in the PDO documentation.

Postgresql for the given query is able to serve the first row in `0.28ms` as per the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

And my aim is to start processing rows as quicker as possible, even if further batches of rows will come with some network overhead.

How I determined that it fetches all the rows:

1. Indirectly: it takes the same time to `break` after the first row or to iterate over the whole dataset
2. I captured the traffic with `tcpdump` and checked that it fetches all the rows.

So, the question is: is it possible to make `PDO` to fetch in a row-by-row (or some reasonable small batches) on demand mode?

Comment: I'm unsure, but have you seen this (PDO::FETCH_LAZY flag): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462156/php-pdofetch-lazy-not-creating-object-variable-names-as-they-are-accessed and from PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: @threadp `FETCH_LAZY` is a misleading name, it does not do what it sounds it should :-D

Comment: Right, I just got that from your answer :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query, [\PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => \PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL]);
```

So the statement must be created with a `\PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL` option

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php